# How do I apply Euler angles around a point?

Tags: math, vector, rotation

I have 2 vectors in 3d space, A and B, and a set of Euler angles. How can I get B's new position after having rotated it around A using the Euler angles?

I've tried using rotation matrices, and found a way to convert the Euler angles to a rotation matrix, but could not find out how to apply the matrix to B.

Comment: Have you tried to compute the matrix-vector product `(rotation matrix) * B`?

Comment: How would I go about computing that?

Comment: If you're doing it by hand, I suggest reading a course on matrix-vector product. [The wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) is not too bad. If you're using a programming language such as python or R or maple, there should be a standard library function for that, and possibly shorthand notation such as `@` or `.` for the multiplication operator. So if `M` is the matrix and `B` the vector, you can write something like `M@B` or `M.B` or `numpy.matmul(M, B)` or `M.times(B)` or `M*B` or something else. Refer to the documentation of whichever software you're using.

Comment: In fact I strongly suggest reading a course on linear algebra and matrices. This will be incredibly useful to you, whatever you do in the future. Matrices are useful in **all** areas of computer science, from geometry to machine learning. It's important to understand what they are and what they represent.

Comment: Thanks, I got it with the Wikipedia page. I'll also try to learn some linear algebra too.